# Converting a string with commas into int, in swift

Tags: ios, swift

`let y = "1,312,000.99"`
`let z = (y as NSString).intValue`

I want to get z to be equal to `1312000`. So basically:

1. String should get converted to int
2. The integer should not have commas
3. Anything after the decimal should be ignored.

Comment: And what stops you from doing that?

Comment: I wanted to know if any of the iOS native APIs do that..

Answer (score 2):

> 1. String should get converted to int
> 2. The integer should not have commas
> 3. Anything after the decimal should be ignored.

I would argue that you need to do those in reverse:

1. Get rid of everything after the decimal place
2. Remove the none-numerical values
3. Convert it to an `Int`

There are a number of ways you might do this

You could use `CharacterSet.decimalDigits`, something like...

```
"1,312,000.99".components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
```

this is kind of messy, as the one thing I've not done, is remove the `.99`, but that could be done something like...

```
var value = "1,312,000.99"
value = String(value[value.startIndex..<value.firstIndex(of: ".")!])
```

**note:** I'm not checking to see if `firstIndex` is `nil` which it might be, so you'll need to compensate for that.

Another, possibly better, solution would be to make use of a `NumberFormatter`

```
let formater = NumberFormatter()
formater.numberStyle = .decimal
formater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_AU")
let number = formater.number(from: "1,312,000.99")
```

Then you could just cast it to an `Int` value

```
let intValue = Int(number!)
```

Again, check `number` as it may be `nil`

Comment: The use of the number formatter is probably best but you may need to set a specific locale depending on the string. If the string is always formatted with `,` for the thousands-separator and `.` for the decimal separator then you must set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`. Otherwise it won't work on devices set to a locale that uses different separators (and digits).

Comment: @rmaddy Good advice!

Comment: A locale of "English" isn't sufficient. It's used in many countries with different decimal formatting. Picking a country is far more important than a language.

Comment: @rmaddy But `en_US_POSIX` doesn't work :P

Comment: You're right. Try just `en_US`, that works. But just `en` won't either, at least for some users.

Comment: You may also hardcode `groupingSeparator`/`thousandSeparator` here too.

Comment: @user28434 Plenty options available, perhaps the OP should read the documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this:

```
//Create a NumberFormatter that takes input strings with comma thousands separators and at least 1 decimal place
let inputFormatter = NumberFormatter()
inputFormatter.format = "###,###,###,###.#"
inputFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier:  "en_US_POSIX")

var numberString = "1,234,567.88"

//Convert the input string to an Int (which truncates the decimal portion)
if let value = inputFormatter.number(from: numberString)?.intValue {
    print(value)
    //print( outputString)
} else {
    print("Can't convert")
}
```

Comment: `NumberFormat format` is only for macOS, not iOS.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh dear. So it is. (The docs make it easy to miss single-platform items like that.) I wasn't able to get the thousandsSeparator to work correctly. Do you have example code using that?